# Which verb with "benefit"? "Come with" "have" "offer"

Tags: word-choice

These generic sentences should suffice

> This comes with a lot of benefits.
>   This has a lot of benefits.
>   This offers a lot of benefits.

I don't know how each of them sounds so I ask you to tell me the best option and which to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first sentence

> This comes **with** a lot of benefits.
>
> They are friends **with** benefits.

using "with" expresses benefits which are additional and nice but not necessarily the primary reason for choosing *something*.

In your second sentence

> This has **a lot** of benefits.

expresses a multitude of positive attributes and is often expressed as

> This has **many** benefits.

Your third sentence

> This **offers** a lot of benefits.
>
> If you buy this SUV to carry the kids around, it **offers** the additional benefit of four wheel drive for better traction in bad weather.

suggests there is additional up-side to *something* which the receiver of the additional benefits may not have considered.